# How to Wrap a REST API POST nested object with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, graphql, wrapper

I am trying to figure out how to wrap mutate a nested object with graphql mutations, if possible. For instance I have the following schema:

```
type Equipment{
  assetId: ID 
  assetName: String 
  assetTag: String 
  createdAt: String 
  updatedAt: String 
  available: Boolean 
  category: Category 
  purchaseAt: String 
  purchaseCost: Float 
  serial: String 
  notes: String 

}

type Category{
  categoryId: ID,
  name: String
}

type Mutation {
    equipamento( e: EquipmentInput): Equipment
  }

input EquipmentInput{
  assetName: String 
  assetTag: String 
  available: Boolean  
  purchaseAt: String 
  category: CategoryInput
  purchaseCost: Float 
  serial: String 
  notes: String 

}
input CategoryInput{
   categoryId: ID
   name : String
}
```

This is the POST call on REST. This call works

```
    {


        "assetName": "Dell Laptop E5570",
        "assetTag": "A0001",
        "available": false,
        "category":{
         "categoryId": 1
        } ,
        "purchaseAt": "2018-09-10",
        "purchaseCost": 1200.00,
        "serial": "Serial",
        "notes": "Novo"


    }
```

I am trying to do a equivalent on GraphQL using graphql-yoga, but category is a nested object and the create call fail on REST service.

````
  equipamento: (parent, args) => {
      const equipment = {
        assetName: args.e.assetName,
        assetTag: args.e.assetTag,
        available: args.e.available,
        category: args.e.category.categoryId,
        purchaseAt: args.e.purchaseAt,
        purchaseCost: args.e.purchaseCost,
        serial: args.e.serial,
        notes: args.e.notes
      }
      return fetch(`${equipmentURL}/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(equipment),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      }).then(res => res.json());
    }```

Console Log for the GraphQL is
```{"assetName":"Dell Laptop E5570","assetTag":"A0001","available":false,"category":1,"purchaseAt":"2018-09-10","purchaseCost":1200,"serial":"Serial","notes":"Novo"}```

So the question is, how can i format my mutation to have nested object?
````

Comment: `category: { categoryId: args.e.category.categoryId },` ?

Comment: Many thanks @xadm your solution is better than i was doing

`category: JSON.parse('{ "categoryId":'+args.e.category.categoryId+ "}")`

Comment: :D you can try to do it in one line (as property names are the same): `const equipment = { ...args.e, category: { categoryId: args.e.category.categoryId } };`

Comment: Okay thanks @xadm . This is the link for the [project] (https://gitlab.com/asacur/it-asset-management-microservices/-/blob/master/api-gateway-graphql/src/index.js) if you want to give more tips.